# Parsing using C#

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

This application works perfectly

```
        var myValue = txtBox1.Text ?? "";
      var splittedValue = myValue.Split(',');
       if (splittedValue.Length != 3)
      {
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter a valid values !", "Message", 


         MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        return;
    }
    txtBox2.Text = (splittedValue[0]);
    txtBox3.Text = (splittedValue[1]);
    txtBox4.Text = (splittedValue[2]);
```

Best Answer. thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Pretty much identical to your previous question [Parse strings using C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26380261/parse-strings-using-c-sharp)

Comment: I asked this question before but no body understood what I meant so i asked this question once more!

Comment: Why would you want to parse one text box to put data into other text boxes?  Why don't you let the user enter specific data into a specific text box?

Comment: @chrisjesus Then **edit** your previous question instead of creating a new one.

Comment: The other text boxes will only show details that entered by the user.So user can only enters the required details and then click the Parse button which will distribute the input into three text boxes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not really understant the purpose but, to reply to your question, you can bind to the appropriate event of the textbox (TextChanged or LostFocus) and do something similar of what you've done :

```
        var myValue = txtBox1.Text ?? "";
        var splittedValue = myValue.Split(',');
        if (splittedValue.Length != 3)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter a valid values !", "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            return;
        }
        txtBox2.Text = (splittedValue[0]);
        txtBox3.Text = (splittedValue[1]);
        txtBox4.Text = (splittedValue[2]);
```

Comment: Can the value of `TextBox.Text` ever be null? Plus after the MessageBox is closed the code will continue to throw an exception if the array length is less than 3.

Comment: In this case, Can I open another If TextBox.Text ==null ?

Comment: when I have no input in the Text Box it gives me it throws an exception

Comment: @ Ash Burlaczenko : Exact, after the MessageBox.Show, it will be nice to have a `return;`. The textbox.text should not return null but only an empty string. As you can see, to be sure I used the txtBox1.Text ?? "".

Comment: Luke thank you very much for your help and you a star:)

Answer (score 3):

If you want to count the number of commas in your string, you can use the `Enumerable.Count` which takes a predicate:

```
if (txtBox1.Text.Count(ch => ch == ',') > 2)
{ 
}
```